# AngularJS $compile odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSBin here about the problem I'm seeing:

http://jsbin.com/tudiwetemudo/8/edit

If you observe the console while you run this on Chrome, you'll notice the following: the innerHTML will be compiled and evaluated correctly in Chrome:

[image: console.info(clonedElement)]

Now, observe the result after trying to console.info the innerHTML by itself:

[image: console.info(clonedElement[0].innerHTML)]

My problem is this: why does innerHTML return the template html rather than the compiled html, and how can I get the compiled html as string?

Comment: I did not see any info from firefox console, does anyone also have this issue?

Comment: @ABOS did you press the Run with JS button on the JSBin UI? This same problem actually replicates on firefox for me now that I try it.

Comment: Yup, I can see the info from chrome console, not firefox. In order to see the parsed html in chrome, I have to wrap the console part in a $timeout, ie $timeout(function(){
      console.info(clonedElement);
      console.info(clonedElement[0].innerHTML);
    }, 2000);

Comment: Seems like just using $timeout without any time parameter (dom-ready style) fixes the problem also. Wonder what's causing it though.